# Best way to achieve full quality remote desktop?

Tags: windows, networking, remote-desktop

I want to share the same computer amongst multiple users using remote desktop (or other applications of the sort), and have each user have their own workstation with less powerful, older machines that connects seamlessly to the larger host computer and it will function normally with no restrictions in terms of visual styles, graphics processing, gaming etc... All the workstations will have gigabit connection to the host computer, and will have their own screen and mouse+keyboard. What would be the best way to achieving this? Thanks.

P.S. it will be worth noting that the host computer will be a Windows7 machine...

Comment: The consumer level versions of Windows 7 only allow a single user to logged into it at a time.

Comment: You're not going to get decent gaming performance out of Remote Desktop. It's just not designed for that. You'd be better off upgrading the workstations if you really care about "full quality".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows server will probably be the easiest setup and feature-rich solution, but it obviously comes with a price; you didn't mention any financial constraints so this would be my recommendation.

Comment: Good... the purpose is to run one single computer/server setup rather than have many individual computers so that the resources can be better utilized when there are fewer or no users using the computer... It would also help save electricity... The thought was that given a high-speed connection to the host, there should be no reason why a seamless, high quality remote connection could not be established, and thus function just like a normal computer would.

Comment: that will cost a fortune for the server that can do it for more than a few concurrent connections, and for all the CALs needed.

Comment: That is true... The server load caused by high quality remote desktop is high, maybe even too high for this to be cost effective?